# RxJS: sequentially concat a variable number of inner Observables

Tags: rxjs

I need to sequentially concat a variable number of inner Observables and stop as soon as the first one resolved to a given result. 
See example below or [here on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-puatyd?file=index.ts) where I use `concatMap`, but this works with a fixed number of inner Observables only.

```js
const values = [1, 4, 6, 3, 9];

getRemoteValue(values[0]).pipe(
  concatMap(result => result ? of(result) : getRemoteValue(values[1])),
  concatMap(result => result ? of(result) : getRemoteValue(values[2])),
  concatMap(result => result ? of(result) : getRemoteValue(values[3])),
  concatMap(result => result ? of(result) : getRemoteValue(values[4]))
).subscribe(success => console.log(success ? 'found it' : 'failed'));



function getRemoteValue(input: number): Observable<boolean> {
  console.log(`checking ${input}`)
  // this would be an async remote call in real life
  const value = _.random(10); 
  return of(value === input);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Observable, of, from, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, single, find } from 'rxjs/operators';

const values = [1, 4, 6, 3, 9];

function getRemoteValue(input: number): Observable<boolean> {
  console.log(`checking ${input}`)
  // this would be an async remote call in real life
  const value = _.random(10);
  return of(value === input);
}

from(values).pipe(
  concatMap(getRemoteValue),
  find((v) => typeof v === 'boolean' && v === true)
)
.subscribe(success => {
    console.log('success:', success);
    console.log(success ? 'found it' : 'failed');
  }
);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-8drx84?file=index.ts)

Comment: I spoke to soon, sorry. 

I missed that your getRemoteValue function no longer returns an Observable but a plain boolean, making it synchronous.
How would I go about it if getRemoteValue is returning an Observable?